# How to count emails from various folders and subfolders of Outlook using vba?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, office-automation

I am trying to count the number of emails from different folders and subfolders of Outlook using vba. I also want the output to show the date of the last email in these folders. My code only gets the count and date from one folder at a time but I want them all at once. This is ow the shared email looks with its folders and subfolders.

```
>"Shared Mailbox Name"
>>Inbox
>>>Folder one
>>>>A
>>>>B
>>>>C
>>>Folder two
>>>>D
>>>>E
>>>>F
>>>>G
```

I want the result to show number of emails of all these folders together and not one by one. A, B, C, D, E, F, G.

```
sub ProcessFolders(Folders)
```

for each folder in Folders
if Folder.DefaultItemType = olMailItem Then
Debug.Print "---------  " & folder.Name
End If
ProcessFolders(folder.Folders)
next
end sub

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over all folder recursively to count the number of items. The following code shows how to iterate over all subfolders in Outlook:

```
Private Sub processFolder(ByVal oParent As Outlook.MAPIFolder)

        Dim oFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
        Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem

        Debug.Print(oParent.Items.Count)    

        For Each oMail In oParent.Items

        'Get your data here ...

        Next

        If (oParent.Folders.Count > 0) Then
            For Each oFolder In oParent.Folders
                processFolder oFolder
            Next
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It does not seem to work. Can you merge it to the original code and post it maybe I am making some silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

To add the required folders to the collection:

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant

Sub Steuerung_AddFoldersToCollection()
    
    Dim objMailboxFolder As Folder
    Set objMailboxFolder = Session.Folders("shared mailbox name") 'folders of your current account

    Dim objInboxFolder As Folder
    Set objInboxFolder = objMailboxFolder.Folders("Inbox")
       
    'Creates a list to which folders to be counted can be appended
    Dim colList As Collection
    Set colList = New Collection
    
    Dim objFolder As Folder
    Dim subF As Folder
    
    'Adds all subfolders of 'Folder one' to the list
    Set objFolder = objInboxFolder.Folders("Folder one")
    
    For Each subF In objFolder.Folders
        Debug.Print "Adding folder: " & subF
        colList.Add subF
    Next subF
    
    'Adds all subfolders of 'Folder two' to the list
    Set objFolder = objInboxFolder.Folders("Folder two")
    For Each subF In objFolder.Folders
        Debug.Print "Adding folder: " & subF
        colList.Add subF
    Next subF
    
    'Iterates over the folder list
    Dim k As Integer
    
    For k = 1 To colList.count
        Debug.Print "Folder being processed: " & colList.item(k)
        'Call Arrayfüllen(colList.item(k), k)
    Next k

    ' no comment on the usability of the rest of the code
    
End Sub
```