# How to count all the emails from every folder and subfolder of a shared email in outlook using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, outlook-2010, office-automation

There is a shared inbox in my Outlook and I would like to count all the emails in every folder and subfolder of this shared inbox.

So far I have this code which gives a count of one subfolder at a time.  But I need the count of all the subfolders which consist of any email at one time.

```
    Sub HowManyEmails()

    Dim objOutlook As Object, objnSpace As Object, objFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim EmailCount As Integer
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objnSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    On Error Resume Next
    Set objFolder = Application.Session.PickFolder
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        MsgBox "No such folder."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    EmailCount = objFolder.Items.Count

    MsgBox "Number of emails in the folder: " & EmailCount, , "email count"

    Dim dateStr As String
    Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim msg As String
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set myItems = objFolder.Items
    myItems.SetColumns ("SentOn")
    ' Determine date of each message:
    For Each myItem In myItems
        dateStr = GetDate(myItem.SentOn)
        If Not dict.Exists(dateStr) Then
            dict(dateStr) = 0
        End If
        dict(dateStr) = CLng(dict(dateStr)) + 1
    Next myItem

    ' Output counts per day:
    msg = ""
    For Each o In dict.Keys
        msg = msg & o & ": " & dict(o) & " items" & vbCrLf
    Next
    MsgBox msg

    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objnSpace = Nothing
    Set objOutlook = Nothing
End Sub

Function GetDate(dt As Date) As String
    GetDate = Year(dt) & "-" & Month(dt) & "-" & Day(dt) & "-"
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over folders tree recursively to get the numbers, for example, here is the skeleton for that:

```
Private Sub processFolder(ByVal oParent As Outlook.MAPIFolder)

        Dim oFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
        Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem

        Debug.Print(oParent.Items.Count)    

        For Each oMail In oParent.Items

        'Get your data here ...

        Next

        If (oParent.Folders.Count > 0) Then
            For Each oFolder In oParent.Folders
                processFolder oFolder
            Next
        End If
End Sub
```

See [How to count emails from various folders and subfolders of Outlook using vba?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71223007/how-to-count-emails-from-various-folders-and-subfolders-of-outlook-using-vba/71228020#71228020).